# How to get data from php and pass it into another oojs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

What i am trying to achieve? -> I need to append the values title and url from sql.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2017-06-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

  {
  "title": "Click for Google",
  "url": "http://google.com/",
  "start": "2017-06-28"
  }]
```

What I tried ? ->

```
 $.ajax({  
  type: 'GET',  
  url: 'eventcalendar.php', 

  dataType:'JSON',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response[0]);
    return response;
    }
 });
```

What i got? ->

```
{"title":"Example","start":"2017-06-21","end":"2017-06-
    22","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com"}{"title":"Holiday","start":"2017-06-
  23","end":"2017-06-24","url":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}
```

My php code:->

```
            <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        include 'announcements/db.php';

        $sql = mysql_query("select title, start, end, url from eventcalendar");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $userinfo = array();

        while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $userinfo[] = $row_user;

                    }
        echo json_encode($userinfo);
        ?>
```

I need to get the value from mysql and update it inside the events: so that all title tag from sql would be shown

*** I am a newbie and this is my first code. Please help and advice if you have better option. Thanks a ton !!**

Comment: *I am a newbie and this is my first code*  visit the php manual then you will learn that `mysql_*` functions are depreciated and no longer supported

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks for the information. Can you help with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that you're using the [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) lib.

Aside from the deprecated mysql_* functions, I think you got a little confused with the ajax usage.

The success function will only be triggered when the ajax resolves and with a successful response. So you could consider two different approaches to that:

1 - Initialize your calendar when you receive the response data:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: 'eventcalendar.php', 
    dataType:'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2017-06-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: response
        });
    }
});
```

2 - Refresh the events in the calendar when the ajax is resolved. In this case, you could use the FullCalendar's built-in method:

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvents', response);
}
```

Hope I helped and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Works like a charm .. You are right. I have confused a lot about it. Thanks for noticing and explaining ...